# В полях базы данных отображается ?????? вместо русских слов

Tags: sql, laravel, oracle, linux-mint, кириллица

Использую Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa как среду разработки.

Sql developer Version 20.2.0.175 с встроенным Oracl клиентов для соединения с базой данных oracle 9i.

Laravel 8.

Проблема в том, что отображается ???? вместо к примеру СКЛАД при выборке с базы данных как на  SQLdeveloper так и через  laravel.

Сопоставил настройки с WIndows 7 Sql developer Version 20.2.0.175,там отображается кириллица.

Выставил  NLS_LANG на Linux, но не дает результата.

Конвектировать в самом sql запросе тоже не дает результата,как быть?

Comment: Как с Ораклом не могу сказать, но в Мускуле/Постгресе при подключении выбирается кодировка, эта опция драйвера - "charset" и "collation". Попробуйте указать `'charset' => 'utf8'`. Подключения описаны в "config/database.php", если соединяетесь в обход этого, напишите в вопросе как. Вообще напишите все детали.

Comment: Проблема была в самой базе данных. База была с кодировкой WE8MSWIN1252. Посмотрел это в таблице nls_database_parameters. Перевести не удалось на UTF-8. Забэкапил базу,создал новую с UTF-8 кодировкой, загрузил дамп и все, кириллица отображает отлично.